# How to handle improper Data Coming from CSV in Informatica

Tags: informatica-powercenter, informatica-powerexchange, informatica-data-integration-hub

I have source file (CSV) and need to load into target (Oracle). But I got an error

**FR_3065 ROW[4],Filed [Student_rollnumber]:Invalid Number:[.].The row will be skipped**

CSV TABL

```
Student_rollnumber,Studnet_Name,Marks,Subjects
10,'Revanth',70,"Maths",
11,'Satish',85,Science
12,'Anil',75,"Java
",
13,'Surya',90,"C++",
14,'Ramana',85,"python",
15,'Sudheer'70,"Informatica
",
16,'Prakash',85,"SQL"
```

I found that in line number 4 the qouts and comma(",) are in the next line how to concat that both ("Java",) And make it single column(Subject)

Comment: can you try this - Go to session configuration after double clicking the session. You will find something called Custom Properties. give the attribute name to be `MatchQuotesPastEndOfLine` and enter its value to be 'Yes'.)

Answer (score 0):

`MatchQuotesPastEndOfLine` mentioned by Koushik should work.

Alternatively you may use sed with below pattern to replace `newline+"` with simply just a `"` - as a result removing the new line at the end of quoted string.

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n"/"/g'
```

Feel free to test this [gist](https://sed.js.org/?gist=fef4b3d16d07cb492ba94a44b3643245).

This however will remove just the ending new line and will not help if it's anywhere in the middle. As said, the `MatchQuotesPastEndOfLine` mentioned by Koushik is the best possible solution.

Above has been based on this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/114943/can-sed-replace-new-line-characters).

Comment: Hi Koushik Thank You , But I didn't understand this sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n"/"/g'

Comment: Hi Koushik , There are two source files (Csv) of them is above table and other table says which school are this students . we have used student table as source and school table as lookup table. The target was DB(Oracle). Now we need to reslove this (",) issues from at the source only . The table which you seeing in the above is not Target it is the source

Comment: MatchQuotesPastEndOfLine This was works 
Thank You Koushik